# AJAX Post is not Sending Params

Tags: javascript, ajax

Req: in web application using struts/velocity

JavaScript need to pass parameter to a method in Java class. I have used AJAX post call to servlet. But not able to receive the parameter in action class.

**JavaScript function**

```
funtion posttoservlet(){
var id=2
var param="Count="+id;
var xmlhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST","DataServlet.action",true);
xmhttp.setrequestheader('contenttype','plain/text');
xmlhttp.send(param);
}
```

**`struts.xml`**

```
<action name="DataServlet" method="getfromjs" class=com.test.servletpost>
</action>
```

**`servletpost.java`**

```
public void getfromjs(){

syso(servletactioncontext.getrequest().getparameter("Count")); // This is printing null instead of printing "2". Please advise.
}
```

I'm confused why the parameter are not posted properly

Comment: Can you use jQuery. Just asking.

Comment: I will have to check that, if you u have solution pls post. My concern is servlet or action is called but parameter is not posted.

Comment: I have posted a solution that doesn't require jQuery... Kindly check it out...

Comment: Did the solution help you, Radha?

Comment: Thanks Praveen, it did work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`setRequestHeader`](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-setrequestheader()-method) is wrong:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

The current code, doesn't set the request headers. This invalid syntax might also throw an error. Try the above. And note that JavaScript is CaSe SeNsItIvE.